# .clone() is affecting actual HTML not the copy

Tags: jquery, html, clone, innerhtml

I am trying to take a `clone`(innerHtml) of one div and made some changes in that `copy` not in my page, but when i'm trying the following code, changes is happening in my page not in the cloned variable string. what i missed?

```
var layoutCopy;
$layoutCopy = $('.report').clone();
$(".holders",layoutCopy).each(function() 
{
    var placeHolder = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $(this).replaceWith(placeHolder);
});
```

Comment: You set `$layoutcopy`, yet use `layoutCopy` - note the missing `$` prefix.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan ooopz! thanku very much!

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan is right.. since the **layoutCopy** in null.. the selector starts searching from the whole **document**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var layoutCopy;
$layoutCopy = $('.report').clone();
$(".holders",layoutCopy).each(function() 
{
    var placeHolder = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $(this).replaceWith(placeHolder);
});
```

You forgot the `$` at `$(".holders",layoutCopy)` change it to:
`$(".holders",$layoutCopy)` to get it working as expected.

Since `layoutCopy` won't be your copy it will modify your main layout